# IIS 10 Express performance issues

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

Upgraded to VS2015 yesterday and noticed when running our web application locally that the performance is awful - Chrome dev tools shows requests for scripts, images and fonts etc. taking upwards of 60 seconds to complete which makes debugging a nightmare.

Has anyone else had similar issues with IIS Express 10? I've tried disabling failed request tracing as suggested [here](http://forums.iis.net/post/1969920.aspx) (it's an old thread though) but it made zero difference to the speed.

This is definitely an IIS Express 10 issue as I've just uninstalled it and reverted to version 8 and the problem has gone away. For now we'll keep using 8 but as I couldn't find anything online about this issue I wanted to raise it and see if I'm the only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I eventually worked this one out: in our organization we have home drives that are mapped to network locations. With IIS Express 10 the default location for logging is set to `%IIS_USER_HOME%` which for me was the network folder.

By default, trace logging is enabled which results in a ~500kb log file for *each resource* on the page (images, scripts, style-sheets etc.) and this is what caused the slow page loading due to the amount of data being saved across the network.

The fix is fairly straightforward: within the solution directory, open the **.vs\config** folder and edit the **applicationhost.config** file. Find the `<sites>` collection and update the folder location for `logFile` and `traceFailedRequestsLogging` to a local path, for example:

```
<siteDefaults>
    <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="c:\IISExpress\Logs" />
    <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="c:\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
</siteDefaults>
```

If required you can also disable trace logging by setting `enabled="false"` in the above snippet.

With these changes made, IIS Express 10 was back to normal and running just as quick as previous versions.